# Is there a plug-in for Visual Studio 2010 to query XML file using LINQ/XPATH?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, visual-studio-2010

There is an XML file. I need to do some statistics on it (e.g. how many nodes don't have a particular attribute, etc.). I am not seeing anything that would allow me doing that right off the bat. Any suggestions? I am using XML Tree plugin for Chrome at the moment but not only it's outside of VS but it also doesn't work for me sometime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found this thing: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c5d4671c-2e29-4452-b039-6f931b7b1155/. Appears doing what I needed and integrates into VS IDE nicely.